# Does the [zabbix] tag belong on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have recently encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601818/ec2-centos7-zabbix-3-4-administration-and-conf-panel-missing-on-front-end) in the Triage queue and was unsure how to rate it. My gut feeling says it has nothing to do with programming and would rather belong on Super User or Server Fault.

Then I saw that there was a [zabbix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zabbix) tag and investigated further. A lot of questions seem to go unanswered, or have nothing to do with programming.

Here are some examples:

- [A user can't add a host to their monitoring system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598506/zabbix-add-host)
- [How to configure zabbix in kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466063/configure-zabbix-monitoring-tool-on-kubernetes-cluster-in-gcp)
- [How can I do the thing? Help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485473/zabbix-get-amount-of-active-users-connection-for-rabbit-mq-cluster)

From what I could gather so far, the vast majority of questions seem to either focus on how to configure zabbix (which I *think* is off-topic), or at the very least are low quality questions.

The question is now, do these kind of questions belong on Stack Overflow?

Comment: It has an api, so yes.  At least asaveljevs worked for the company, pretty like that Richlv does currently.  But they can't effectively moderate the tag, not enough rep.  Why companies think that an SO presence is useful when their tag shows a 100% unanswered rate for the current week is unclear to me, it is not great advertising.  Life is not easy in open source land.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense then to change the description of the tag to clarify it's only for the API and not for configuring the application?

Comment: Feel free to propose an edit.  Not that this ever slows end-users down.  I *think* it encourages them, they always want help from somebody "that knows this stuff".

Comment: Do they have a presence on SO, or just employee's with SO accounts who might've answered some questions in the past?

Comment: to be fair, configuration seems on topic if its a tool used by developers

Comment: @Orangesandlemons I don't think it's a development tool, but rather a monitoring tool for servers

Comment: @DavidStockinger is correct. This isn't as much about programming or even API calls (though available, aren't used very often in most cases), this should belong in ServerFault as it's more akin to being used in an Enterprise environment. I like the idea of splitting the tags to keep zabbix-api in SO and zabbix-server in SF.

Comment: @DanNeely That is the same thing! Or at best it would depend on their swag. It's not like they invest in SO or something.

Comment: Anyway, the _real_ question is, do we really want to get rid of this tag? It would mean we'd have to come up with a proper pun.

Comment: @MrLister Not it's not.  The latter is equivalent to my being on SO, but only in my personal capacity; not as a representative of my employer.  (Who to be fair doesn't offer a platform/etc where SO could be a meaningful support channel.)   A good example of the former done right is what I've seen on newer MS technologies where  questions unanswered by the community invariably get a reply from "Name - MSFT" where Name is an MS developer of the stack in question.

Comment: @MrLister I would not get rid of it. Instead, I would do as Andrew suggested and rename it [zabbix-api]. All questions that do not have anything to do with the API should be evaluated. High-quality questions (I assume there are not many) should be migrated to SF, while low quality questions will be deleted.